# Elements inserted into map cleared after function executes

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, vector

I am trying to create a function which converts the elements of a vector of custom objects called Project to a map with the 'key' as the ID of those projects, stored in a member variable, and the mapped value the projects themselves. To do this I have a simple function which is passed a pointer to vector as argument, loops through the (dereferenced) vector, and for each element retrieves its ID and uses the [ ] map operators to assign the pair as shown. The map declaration is as follows:

```
map<int, Project*> unassigned_projects;
```

Here is the function:

```
void Solution::setup_project_map(vector<Project>* project_list) {
    for (int i = 0; i != size(*project_list); ++i) {
        int project_id = (*project_list)[i].get_project_id();
        this->unassigned_projects[project_id] = &((*project_list)[i]);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that it makes the correct assignments inside the function (you can see what the results look like in the debugger [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UORbu.png)), but as soon as the function exits all the data stored in the objects resets to default values as shown [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWpiB.png).

It's my understanding that this would make sense if I was passing the actual vector object to the function, as once the function had finished the temporary object would have been deleted and so any pointers to elements of that object would also become undefined, or if I was using a range-for loop and it was creating copies of the elements. However, since I'm passing the vector by reference and directly dereferencing it at every stage, the values should remain unchanged inside and outside the function. I have had problems in the past with not properly using pass-by-reference though so I suspect this is where I'm going wrong in some way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mixing a `vector<Project>` and a `map<int, Project*>` is going to be a problem.  Any reason why you are not using a `map<int, Project>`?

Comment: Well, I was trying to avoid having to create duplicates of the projects, but it's probably not such a huge issue if that would solve the problem. Why is doing it this way likely to cause problems?

Comment: Well, if the vector goes out of scope then all your pointers int the map point to objects that were destroyed.

Comment: That makes sense. The original vector certainly shouldn't be going out of scope here though (see comment on post below).

Comment: We can't help with code we can't see, we can only make guesses, post a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You are storing pointers to `Project`s in the map, but if the `vector` dies (due to going out of scope eventually, we can't tell from your code where that happens) then so does every `Project` in it. All the pointers in your map now point to `Project`s that no longer exist. If you try to read from the dead projects, you get undefined behavior and the debugger may or may not display garbage or an error.

You should figure out who manages the lifetime of your `Project` objects, and if copying them is necessary or not to keep them alive. Right now the `vector` always manages the lifetime, which is a problem if the map outlives the vector. You could share ownership to the `Project`s, you could transfer ownership in the function, or you could create copies in the functions to separate the lifetime. The first two options are best implemented using `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`, respectively.

Comment: not just if map outlives the vector but also if the vector is modified in some way which invalidates its iterators

Comment: The vector is contained within an algorithm class which contains a set of data in which the project_list is stored and also the objects which are executing this function, so it shouldn't be deleted until after the master instance of the algorithm is deleted. It certainly shouldn't be deleted straight after this function has finished executing, and I can see in the debugger that as soon as the function exits the data is cleared.

Comment: @whelkstrider If you want a better answer you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is no obvious problem in the code you provided.